# Ethereum token transfer using contract functions?

Tags: ether, tokens

I have created contract token using solidity realtime compiler and got web3js

```
var initialSupply = 1;
var tokenName = 'test' ;
var decimalUnits = 0.0014 ;
var tokenSymbol = 'TEST' ;
var mytokenContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"standard","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burnFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_extraData","type":"bytes"}],"name":"approveAndCall","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"initialSupply","type":"uint256"},{"name":"tokenName","type":"string"},{"name":"decimalUnits","type":"uint8"},{"name":"tokenSymbol","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Burn","type":"event"}]);
var mytoken = mytokenContract.new(
initialSupply,
tokenName,
decimalUnits,
tokenSymbol,
{
from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
data: '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',
gas: 4000
}, function(e, contract){
console.log(e, contract);
if (typeof contract.address != 'undefined') {
console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
}
})
```

By using the above code we created the token. We got the contract address from the deploy process

To access the contract functions, Get abiarray interface from the contract and using this below coding for transfer the token but its not working. my coding is,

```
var abi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"standard","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"burnFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_extraData","type":"bytes"}],"name":"approveAndCall","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"initialSupply","type":"uint256"},{"name":"tokenName","type":"string"},{"name":"decimalUnits","type":"uint8"},{"name":"tokenSymbol","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Burn","type":"event"}];
undefined
> var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at("0x4ae3096e88842e77bd99d2ca75cef879f1294f45");
undefined
> contract.balanceOf("0x4ae3096e88842e77bd99d2ca75cef879f1294f45")/10000000000000000;
0
> contract.balanceOf("0x4ae3096e88842e77bd99d2ca75cef879f1294f45")

0
> personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[0], "password")
true
> contract.transfer("0xc478f722f9901af6452ec397305ecea7dca17d2f", 140000000000000000000, {from:"0x4ae3096e88842e77bd99d2ca75cef879f1294f45"});
"0x2a1bb710099283eb010cc252de9962a75f717cca1f99071225aecb4ea99b689d"
> contract.balanceOf("0x4ae3096e88842e77bd99d2ca75cef879f1294f45")

0
> contract.balanceOf("0xc478f722f9901af6452ec397305ecea7dca17d2f")

0
```

When execute the web3.eth.getBalance() function returns the balance for the respcetive address but
using `contract.balanceOf()` function shows zero only.

But I checked(by add custom token section) with [www.myetherwallet.com](https://www.myetherwallet.com/) site "the token transaction" is working fine.

But we can't transfer and get the balance of the token process please help anyone.

Comment: Can you post the contract code? Have you made `balanceOf` mapping public?

Comment: What address is `web3.eth.accounts[0]`?  Have you checked the balance of that? Usually all tokens are assigned initially to the address that created the contract (not the contract address, otherwise they could never be moved).  Also note that `web3.eth.getBalance()` shows you the Ether balance of the address, not the token balance. `contract.balanceOf()` should show you the token balance. Don't confuse the two of these.

Comment: @benjaminion we tried with contract.balanceOf() function for web3.eth.accounts[0] it always shows zero balance. But in the  www.myetherwallet.com we can transfer the token so we confused here

Comment: OK - another thing: you are only allowing 4000 gas in the contract creation. This is nowhere near enough. Try a million or so. What is the return result from the contract creation? My guess is that it 's not being deployed. It might work in a test environment, but definitely not on the real network. And see your duplicate question for a couple of other errors I noticed.

Comment: Our code is deployed successfully and also got the contract address. and also we checked with myetherwallet.com site with add custom token by using this we can transfer the token. but by using contract process we can't do it. please check this https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1c47cf51d0ea3fca027c02fdbf92b4d5d51968216e5229f5cf9314854fa0cc00